# What will happen with PlayerPrefs data after updating the app?

Tags: unity, android

I'm using PlayerPrefs (Unity3D, on Android).

If a user updates my application via the Google Play store, what happens to the data I've stored in PlayerPrefs?

Comment: "The data"? "The file"? "The application"? Please provide additional details about what you're trying to do, what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Im making a game for android(Unity3D).

Comment: as long as the user does not uninstall the app. the data stored in PlayerPrefs will not be deleted. So an app update will not delete you savegame data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store it in:

```
Aplication.persistenDataPath
```

you can be certain, that it won't be deleted after an update. (except the user uninstalls and then reinstalls the game manually)

Answer (score 0):

Unity preferences have [Android preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) underlying it, and they are kept until the user manually uninstall the app.